# How we add foreign key in asp.net identity MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

ApplicationUser Class which inherit with IdentityUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string User_type { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public Enums.Sex Gender { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patients { get; set; }
    public int PatientID { get; set; }

}
```

Patient Class

```
public class Patient
{
    [Key]
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set;}
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

}
```

Controller

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterPatient(RegisterViewModel model)
    {

        MYDb db = new MYDb();
        Patient pt = new Patient();
        pt.BirthDate = model.BirthDate;
        pt.City = model.City;
        pt.Country = model.Country;
        pt.ProfilePicture = model.ProfilePicture;
        pt.FName = model.FName;
        int Pat_id = model.PatientID;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            ApplicationUser myuser = new ApplicationUser();
            model.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            model.IsActive = true;
            myuser.PatientID = Pat_id;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = model.GetUser();
                db.Patients.Add(pt);
                db.SaveChanges();
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                { 
                    var idManager = new IdentityManager();
                    idManager.AddUserToRole(user.Id, model.User_type);
                    //await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View();
    }
```

> i want to make relationship b/w Patient and ApplicationUser  first i
>   add record in patient then "Patient_ID" used as a **foreign key** in
>   ApplicationUser Table but when add data i face this type of error

**Error**

[image]

> Note : data save in **Patient table** but not in **ApplicationUser table** because ApplicationUser not get "**PatientID**" therefore conflict occurred in DB.

I hope this is much clear and its not easy to solve :(

Comment: the error means that whatever value you tried to insert into ApplicationUser as the PatientID, that value does not exist in the PatientID column in the Patients table. So you need to debug your code and check the code is getting the PatientID correctly

Answer (score 0):

In Applicatin User Model Write done this :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string User_type { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public Enums.Sex Gender { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PatientID")] 
    public virtual Patient Patients{ get; set; }
}
```

I think it will work.

Comment: Thanks For reply 
but have same problem Record insert in Patient Table not in ApplicationUser :(

Comment: You Insert data into Patient table. And you want to make PatientID as Foreign Key into ApplicationUser table. am i right?

Comment: Will you apply the edited code?  Why use this line in Patient Class?  `public ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }`

Comment: Ok i removed it but face same problem

Comment: Please help me out this anybody plz

Comment: See this i think it will help you : http://techfunda.com/howto/132/primary-key-and-foreign-key-relationship-in-model

Comment: First You delete all of the data from database then try again

Comment: Please help me 
this is my first effort

Comment: can we add foreign key in Applicationuser model using  asp.net MVC identity model ?